# Python replace year mentions like '85 with 1985

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am using this regular expression to replace all ocurrences of years of the form '85 with 1985 inside a string

```
import re
re.sub("'(\d\d)", "19\1", "Today '45")
```

but the result I get back is far from expected:

```
'Today 19\x01'
```

I would expect to get `Today 1945`. I am wondering what is the proper way to do it. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Make the string raw strings by prefixing with `r`: `re.sub(r"'(\d\d)", r"19\1", "Today '45")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the string a raw string

```
>>> re.sub(r"'(\d\d)", r"19\1", "Today '45")
'Today 1945'
```

Or as [Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348838/python-replace-year-mentions-like-85-with-1985/28348881?noredirect=1#comment45041824_28348881) suggests, Use word boundaries `\b`. They are better as they would help you ignore digits that are not two digits, like `3456`

```
>>> re.sub(r"'(\d{2})\b", r"19\1", "Today '45, '3456")
"Today 1945, '3456"
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj: But the apostrophe shouldn't be in a lookbehind assertion, or it won't be removed.

Comment: oh, i failed to notice  that.. `'(?=\d{2}\b)` or `'(\d{2})\b`

Answer (score 3):

Reference the group with `\g<1>` instead of `\1`:

```
In [21]: re.sub("'(\d\d)", "19\g<1>", "Today '45")
Out[21]: 'Today 1945'
```

or use raw strings:

```
In [22]: re.sub("'(\d\d)", r"19\1", "Today '45")
Out[22]: 'Today 1945'
```

Your code isn't working, because Python [interprets `\1` as a character.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings)